# Append a file's last modification date to its name

Tags: bash, last-modified

I'm struggling to find a way to get the last modification date of every file in a folder and subfolders and append them to their names accordingly. So far I can only append a custom text per file, in this case it's `_Suffix` from this command: `find * -exec mv {} {}_Suffix \;`

Maybe this isn't the best way since my text is inserted at the very end of the file so it changes the file's extension but at least it works :)

But I want to know how to insert the last modification date instead of `_Suffix` and do that for every file recursively.

Comment: can you give an example of an input and what you expect to have from it?

Comment: what happens if you edit one of those files? Is the filename supposed to automatically update?

Comment: @glenn jackman No, although do you known of such script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'for arg; do arg=${arg#./} mod=$(stat -c %x "$arg") base=${arg%.*} ext=${arg#$base}; echo mv -i "$arg" "${base}_${mod%% *}$ext"; done' _ {} +
```

(multiline version for readability):

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'for arg; do
  arg=${arg#./} mod=$(stat -c %x "$arg") base=${arg%.*} ext=${arg#$base}
  echo mv -i "$arg" "${base}_${mod%% *}$ext"
done' _ {} +
```

I left the `echo` there for you to *see* what it's going to run before actually running it. Remove it once you're sure you want to move the files.

It adds what you want *before* the extension but it will completely **FAIL** if:

- A filename doesn't contain a dot
- That file is in a folder path which does contain a dot

It will also not work properly on files with double extensions, e.g. `.tar.gz`

Explanation:
I'm passing all files to a bash script with `find . -type f -exec bash -c '...' _ {} +`
The bash script does the same action for all files: get the modification `date`, discover the `basename` and the `.extension`, then rename the file to `basename_date.extension`

Comment: It has the flaws you mentioned but still it works well. Thanks man

Comment: What would I need to change in the script to append the date at the beginning of the name and leave the rest unchanged?

Comment: @computationalprince, you need to remove `arg=${arg#./}`, change `base=${arg%.*}` into `base=${arg%/*}/` and `_${mod%% *}` into `${mod%% *}_`. Now it works in all cases.